# Change size of a UIImageView in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIImageView` and several `UIView`s in a `UIViewController` on my storyboard, but on a iPhone 4s, part of my `UIImageView` is located on another view.

EDIT:

[image]

I want to reduce my `UIImageView`’s size and get about this result:
[image]

How can I accomplish this in the storyboard and not use any code?

my `UIViewController` in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Auto-layout is the right place to look into for achieving this.
Have a look at this article where auto-layout is explained in a very good detail.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with auto-layout, which means no code. You need to adjust the constraints depending on the size of the screen. This is called **size-class-specific layout**. By default xCode uses size classes but only one. To add more classes you need to do this manually. This is not as technical as it sounds and is fairly easy. It is explained by Apple in the docs here: [Auto Layout Guide: Size-Class-Specific Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH26-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

I think Apple's Documentation explains constraints very well which will solve your problem without any code.

Basically all you do is:

1. Make sure your UIImageView is selected.
2. Press on the constraints button on the bottom of the storyboard's screen(looks like a square).
3. Constrain the view by selecting the pins on the sides of the box (at the top of the popup) and giving constraint values.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: If you look at your constraint between you image view and the long pink rectangle, you set the constraint to "less than, or equal to". You can change this to "equal to" for a quick fix. I think you are in need of using a UIStackView though. I have created a video explaining why and how you should use UIStackViews. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsOFRB3h7g4

Comment: If I set the constraint to «equal to» my image will not change the size, and the pink square and the long green rectangle will come out of the screen down.

Comment: That’s why you should use stack views. They will resize your elements automatically.